# ReactJS - I don't understand the syntax used in this function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop

I am trying to understand this function which is used for a react drag and drop sortable list.

```
moveCard = (dragIndex, hoverIndex) => {
    const { cards } = this.state
    const dragCard = cards[dragIndex]

    this.setState(
      update(this.state, {
        cards: {
          $splice: [[dragIndex, 1], [hoverIndex, 0, dragCard]],
        },
      }),
    )
}
```

Specifically I don't understand the line

```
$splice: [[dragIndex, 1], [hoverIndex, 0, dragCard]],
```

I tried looking up the splice array definition but I just don't understand how this works. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 3):

That is an [immutability helper](https://reactjs.org/docs/update.html). It, for each item in arrays, calls `splice()` on the target with the parameters provided by the item.

For example:

```
const collection = [1, 2, {a: [12, 17, 15]}];
const newCollection = update(collection, {2: {a: {$splice: [[1, 1, 13, 14]]}}});
// Outputs: [1, 2, {a: [12, 13, 14, 15]}]
```

This accesses `collection`’s index 2, key `a`, and does a splice of one item starting from index 1 (to remove 17) while inserting 13 and 14.

Answer (score 1):

That's a property initializer defining a property called `$splice` with the value `[[dragIndex, 1], [hoverIndex, 0, dragCard]]`.

`[[dragIndex, 1], [hoverIndex, 0, dragCard]]` is an array containing:

- An array with `dragIndex` and `1` in it
- Another array with `hoverIndex`, `0`, and `dragCard` in it

The `$splice` property is an [immutability helper](https://reactjs.org/docs/update.html):

> `{$splice: array of arrays}` for each item in arrays call `splice()` on the target with the parameters provided by the item.

So in effect, that code is doing this:

```
const cards = [...this.state.cards];
cards.splice(dragIndex, 1);
cards.splice(hoverIndex, 0, dragCard);
this.setState({cards});
```

...which means it's [**incorrect**](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous). When you're setting state based on existing state, you **must** use the callback version of `setState`. We'd need more context to show you how to implement that correctly with the callback version of `setState` (since you can't rely on `hoverIndex` and `dragIndex` still being correct when the callback occurs). But it would look something like this:

```
// This is GUESSING at several details, such as that the entries in
// `cards` are objects.
const { cards } = this.state;
const cardToRemove = cards[dragIndex];
const addInFrontOf = cards[hoverIndex];
this.setState(prevState => {
    const cards = [...prevState.cards];
    let index = cards.findIndex(cardToRemove);
    if (index != -1) {
        cards.splice(index, 1);
    }
    let index = addInFrontOf ? cards.findIndex(addInFrontOf) : cards.length;
    cards.splice(index, 0, dragCard);
    return {cards};
});
```

...or the equivalent using an immutibility helper, but beware what happens if `dragIndex` is lower than `hoverIndex`.

Note that these three lines:

```
const { cards } = this.state;
const cardToRemove = cards[dragIndex];
const addInFrontOf = cards[hoverIndex];
```

...can be

```
const {
    cards: {
      [dragIndex]: cardToRemove,
      [hoverIndex]: addInFrontOf
    }
} = this.state;
```

...but I think clarity suffers fairly badly there. :-)